# How to encrypt .m files in Objective-C Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, encryption

I wrote several .h and .m files, I want to make .m files inaccessable to others. They can use these methods I defined, but they cannot see how these methods are defined and modify them. Some kind of "Library" or "framework", I don't know, please tell me.

Comment: Either a "library" or "framework" will compile your .m files into a binary file, from which it is impossible to extract the _exact_ source code... although someone very determined might be able to reverse-engineer your program and [see what methods you used](http://blog.securemacprogramming.com/2010/07/on-private-methods/). The framework packages that binary with your header files so other developers can easily integrate your code without reading (or being able to read) the .m files. You'll need to give more information, though, if you want detailed help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it is very helpful, and I want to know how to make framework and library.